# Use Lambda Expressions in a Query (C#)

Tags: c#, lambda

How can I write lambda expression to get all orders who has detail row(s) with descriptions = "PickMe" or "TakeMe"

[image: DB Schema]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
context.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderDetails.Any(d => d.Description == "PickMe" || d.Description == "TakeMe"));
```